# R shiny: Display data set in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to print dataset values in shiny web app. But I am only able to print data set name using below code. How can I print dataset values?

```
library(MASS)
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

mass.tmp <- data(package = "MASS")[3]
mass.datasets <- as.vector(mass.tmp$results[,3])

ui <- fluidPage(

  theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
  titlePanel("Linear Regression Modelling"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("dsname", "Dataset:",choices = c(mass.datasets))
      ,
       uiOutput("x_axis")
      # ,
      # textOutput("txt"),
      #  tableOutput("tab")

    ),
    mainPanel(
      tags$br(),
      tags$br()
  )
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  num_ds <- function(ds)
  {
    nums <- sapply(ds,is.numeric)
    num_ds <- ds[,nums]
    return(num_ds)
  }

  ds_ext <- reactive({  num_ds(input$dsname) })

  output$x_axis <- renderUI({
       col_opts <- get(ds_ext())
       selectInput("x_axis2", "Independent Variable:", choices = names(col_opts))
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Actually I am trying to solve error in above code "Incorrect number of dimensions". I have written function which would return data frame with only numeric variables so that I can analyze. But getting error in line I guess where I am creating object x_axis. pls help.

Comment: Have you tried without the eval statement?

Comment: I think you're looking for `get`, though there's almost certainly a better way to structure your app so you don't need it.

Comment: Use `get` here: `nums <- sapply(get(ds), is.numeric)`

Comment: I replaced statement in function "nums <- sapply(ds,is.numeric)" to the one above. But still getting the same error.